# /wikipedia/en_id not working on MQL query

Tags: google-api, freebase, mql

Does anybody know why is this query not working? It was yesterday:

```
[{  "mid": "/m/02_286",  "key": {
"namespace": "/wikipedia/en_id",    "value": null  }}]
```

I get this response

```
{  "result": []}
```

I want to obtain the ID **38252** so I can obtain a wikipedia link like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/index.html?curid=38252

You can see further details here: https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-cookbook

You can take a look to the query [here](https://www.freebase.com/query?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&q=%7B%22mid%22%3A%22%2Fm%2F02_286%22%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22key%22%3A%7B%22namespace%22%3A%22%2Fwikipedia%2Fen_id%22%2C%22value%22%3Anull%7D%7D)

**EDIT :**

I noticed that with Paris there is an "en_id" key https://www.freebase.com/m/02_286?keys= but with New York city there is no "en_id" key https://www.freebase.com/m/02_286?keys=. Its weird because there was an id a couple of days ago...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not the topic where the /wikipedia/en_id/38252 key lives.  You can find this out by reversing your query like [here](https://www.freebase.com/query?lang=/lang/en&q=%7B%22mid%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull,%22key%22%3a%7B%22namespace%22%3a%22/wikipedia/en_id%22,%22value%22%3a%2238252%22%7D%7D)

```
{
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "key": {
    "namespace": "/wikipedia/en_id",
    "value": "38252"
  }
}
```

The topic that you are looking for is https://www.freebase.com/m/09jm8

Your original query is fine.  It's just that that particular topic doesn't have a /wikipedia/en_id key.  It did up until June 17, as you can see by looking at the historical view:
https://www.freebase.com/m/02_286?keys&lang=en&filter=%2Ftype%2Fobject%2Fkey&historical=true

This is probably a data bug, but you can't fix it by changing your query.

Comment: That was just and example of the type of ID I want to retrieve. But I will like to have the Wikipedia ID for "/m/02_286" (New York City https://www.freebase.com/m/02_286) And it is not working.

Comment: You'll probably get better quality answers if you post consistent examples.